# What part of the AJAX JQUERY code determines placeholder for output data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am using a code from here [Voting system with jQuery, Ajax and PHP](http://www.9lessons.info/2009/08/vote-with-jquery-ajax-and-php.html)

I have manipulated the code a little bit to be used for my purpose, which is to let the user pick fields of interests from right column and move them to the left column, which is her collected interests. The idea is that when the user clicks on a word, it will disappear from that column and will appear in the opposite column.
Now the PHP and mySQL part are working fine, but I can´t figure out couple of things:

1. How can I update both column with the same click-function?
2. Although clicking a word WILL make it disappear, I can´t see what part of the code does that?

Here is my jQuery code:

```
$(function() {
    $(".vote").click(function() {
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        var name = $(this).attr("name");
        var dataString = 'id='+ id ;
        var parent = $(this);

        if (name == 'up') {
            $(this).fadeIn(200).html('<img src="dot.gif" align="absmiddle">');
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "up_vote.php",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                success: function(html) {
                    parent.html(html);
                } 
            });
        }
```

And this is HTML part:

```
<table width="300">
    <tr>
        <td width="150">
            <a href="" class="vote" id="23" name="down">Cinema</a>
            <a href="" class="vote" id="24" name="down">Acting</a>
        </td>   
        <td width="150">
            <a href="" class="vote" id="12" name="up">Sports</a>
            <a href="" class="vote" id="13" name="up">Riding</a>
        </td>   
    </tr>
</table>
```

I want to be able to decide WHERE to output be shown. Thanks for every suggestion

Comment: Thanks Rory McCrossan for editing my text. Looks nice now ;)

Comment: Also how would I do if I wanted to assign 2 different results to two separate DIVs. As it is now I can only output the entire HTML result of the updating page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can output wherever you want, let's say you want the returning result it in a div of class test, you do this:

```
   success: function(html)
    {
   $('.test').html(html);
    }  });
    }
```

Comment: What part of the AJAX JQUERY code determines placeholder for output data? The success function   html is the data returned to your page you can show if wherever you want on your page

Comment: It seems that the new results will be appended to the old ones! How to avoid that?

Comment: $('.test').html(html) content will be replaced with the new data, if you use append instead of .html content will be appended to the old data

Comment: I used `$('.left').html(html);` I called the div ´left´. Here is the div itself: `<div class='left'>`

Comment: Ok, Now I know what was wrong! The `<div class='left'>` was placed inside of the WHILE loop, So I had several of the same div-Id